# How to send 2d array to ajax function in WordPress?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I have an array of values I want to send it to a Php function to insert them in database. I use wordpress so my php handler is admin-ajax.php I sent about sixty values within this array but when I print the return values on the success function to see if they have been sent correctly or not ; I get an empty array of about 1000 value. I do not understand where this huge array comes from and at the same time I want to know if I sent the array in the right way or not, please help me on this it is my first time using ajax with wordpress.

This is my code:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
                'action':'myFunction',
                'values' : 'values'
            },
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

values is 2d array :

```
values[1000][1]=true;
values[1000][2]=flase;
values[1000][3]=true;
values[1001][1]=true;
values[1001][2]=flase;
values[1001][3]=true;
values[1002][1]=true;
values[1002][2]=flase;
values[1002][3]=true;
.
.
.
```

here is my php function it is just for printing values :

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
function myFunction(){
print_r($_POST);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myFunction');
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($your_array); exit;`

Comment: @Uchiha I add it instead to `print_r($_POST)'` and also I add `dataType: 'json'` to ajax function but it still giving me an empty array of 999 elements

Comment: Never ever use `url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` as your `admin-ajax.php` handler. Bad practice. Instead localize it: `wp_localize_script( 'your_custom_script_handle_name', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
));`, and then use `url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,` to call it.